# machine learning , Python

Tags: python

Can someone help me out in solving the problem given below:

We have a column 'Review' in a SFrame for different products. I want to create a word_count column which should count the occurrence of only a given set of selected words and not all the words.

Alternatively, even if we create a word count with all the words in a review, we can still subset the resulting dictionary, which will give a new column of dictionary with only selected words as the keys of dictionary and the corresponding value.

For example if selected_words = ['Good','Awesome'] , the result should derive word_count = {'Good':1,'Awesome':1} as given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq1Gg.jpg)
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please read about the right etiquette for posting on this site.

Comment: Learn more on [ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

According to me you want some sentimental analysis for differentiate positive and negative reviews .you have to create column with all good and bad words.if review don't contain that word then mark word count as 0 otherwise store count. this problem is similar to differentiate the mail into spam or not spam. to get high accuracy of modal you need creative feature like stemming etc.you have to train your model for large number of features.

for preprocessing, If you want to implement best method with less complexiy is create hash table for each feature word and go through sentence and match hash for each word if hash defined then increase it else leave it. then save all feature hash value in table. do it for all reviews.